# Integration by parts with respect to Gaussian measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

How can we simplify (integrate over the real line)
$$\int-\frac{1}{2}\phi''\phi+\frac{1}{2}x\phi\phi'dm$$
where $m$ is Gaussian measure (i.e. $dm=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$) and we know $\phi(\pm\infty)=\phi'(\pm\infty)=0$

I hope to simplify it to something like $\int\phi'^2dm+\int\phi^2dm+...$ or something friendly in $dx$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compute"? For instance, how would you go computing $\int \phi'^2 \, dm$...?

Comment: @saz I mean simplify. That integral you mentioned is actually easy to compute. This problem come from Ritz method in variation

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$ \big(- \phi'' \phi + x \phi \phi' \big) e^{-x^2/2} = - \frac{d}{dx} \big( \phi \phi' e^{-x^2/2})+(\phi')^2 e^{-x^2/2}.$$

Consequently,

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (-\phi'' \phi + x \phi \phi') \, dm = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\phi')^2 \, dm - \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{d}{dx} (\phi \phi' e^{-x^2/2}) \, dx}_{=0} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\phi')^2 \, dm.$$